# developing C++ in visual studio, is there a way to auto-format when using trailing return type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
    1) auto Init()->void;
    2) auto Init() -> void;
```

in visual studio 2019/2022
When you press ctrl + K. ctrl + D, both cases are valid. But I would like to use method 2)

Comment: Seems like MSVS ignores it so it can't format it, yet. File a bug report that's your best bet. Resharper++ formats it.

Comment: According to this [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-Ignore-spaces-in-declaration-state/726683?space=8&q=format+trailing+return+type), this phenomenon has not been resolved.

Comment: You may use [clang-format](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) instead which will format the code sample above to your preferred variant.